# How do I install a range anti-tip kit into hardwood floor on concrete?

Tags: concrete, flooring, floor, hardwood, stove

I'm preparing to install an anti-tip kit for an electric range. It's a piece of shaped metal designed to be bolted to the floor with two screws or bolts. The floor is hardwood (probably engineered) and we believe it's concrete underneath.

The instructions say to talk to your qualified floor installer...

Do I just get two masonry anchors, drill the hole through the wood and then the concrete and screw in or?

If it's relevant, this is a Kitchenaid anti-tip kit.

Answer (score 1):

The anti-tip kit is a good idea, especially the first time you pull a 25 pound turkey out of the oven!  If you have a 1/2 inch engineered hardwood floor, yes, by all means, drill through the wood and use a masonry screw or anchor to attach the clip.  You will regret it if you don't install this safety clip. Thanksgiving dinner will be on the floor!!!!!!!!

Comment: And of course it's a safety device to prevent burns. Keeping roast turkeys off the floor is just a bonus. It is worth installing, even if you don't mind dropping food.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - for the record, I want to install it to stop the range falling over and killing my kid. But, hey, turkey!